# Problem with Dropbox iPad login modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sdk, dropbox

I have a problem with the Dropbox iPad login modal view controller: sometimes you can't write in the password textfield; you can select it and the keyboard appears, but you can't write. A workaround is to press login, it says you haven't entered the password, you press ok, select it again and now works. It's not very nice for the users. So now the question: have someone found a way to fix the Dropbox SDK or is a problem that I'm the only one to have?

Comment: We cannot possibly answer this without seeing how you set things up.

Comment: Dropbox Login hasn't a setup, i just do 'DBLoginController* controller = [[DBLoginController new] autorelease]; controller.delegate = self; [controller presentFromController:self];'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the Dropbox SDK with an iPad app. I've reviewed their `DBLoginController.h/.m` code. The password control is a simple `UITextField` that is added to a `UITableViewCell`. There are only a few places where the text being typed into the field could be changed on-the-fly. One is `-(BOOL)textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString`. Looking at the code in DBLoginController I see this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
                   shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
                   replacementString:(NSString *)string {
   [self performSelector:@selector(updateActionButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
   return YES;
}
```

This is fine, since it always returns YES.

The next possibility is that the textField is not actually getting focus. The best way to test for this would be to put an NSLog() in the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`. That NSLog() should be hit any time you type a character in the password field. If you are typing and you don't see any NSLog() output, it means the password field doesn't have focus. The next step would be to figure out what *does* have focus and why.

The DBLoginController is a fairly simple class. It shouldn't be hard to track down what is going on.

One final thought: if you have any categories defined on `UITextField`, it might be affecting how some textFields are working.

Comment: The problem is that this malfunction only appears sometimes. It's very difficult to debug. But I'll try. :)

Comment: The problem disappeared when I upgraded to Xcode 4.1 I think it was a problem with the debugger or with the SDK